# Intellij support for Java 17 and GWT

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, java-17

I am trying to set up a project in Intellij with Java 17 and GWT 2.9. I have installed the GWT plugin and trying to configure my project set up.

I am unable to find the option to configure GWT and when I navigate to Project Structure --> JavaEE but I only find JakartaEE option in the listing. I understand that JavaEE is now JakartaEE, since GWT 2.9.0 does not support JakartaEE, what are my option now. how do I configure the project structure. are there any work arounds available?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check related article about adding GWT facet: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/creating-a-module-with-a-gwt-facet.html

Comment: Hi @y.bedrov, Thanks for the reply, I have tried this already. The option suggested in the article (JavaEE or Additional Libraries and Frameworks) is not visible to me, may be coz my JDK version is set to 17. Any more suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with available options? GWT is shown on my side when 17 JDK is used.